# How to add image into collection view cell from local library in ios?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller, uicollectionviewcell, uiactionsheet

I have used a `UICollectionView` to display images. When I click the insert image button, the photos in local library should be added to the `UICollectionCell` using `UIImagePicker`. I declared `UIImageView` in custom cell that is `RACollectionViewCell`. In `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` delegate method of `UIImagePickerView` whenever am writing as `cell.imageview.image = chosenImage`. I am getting error as a *undeclared identifier "cell"*. Please guide me how to solve my issue.

Any help is appreciable, Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
            {
                static NSString *cellID = @"cellID";
                RACollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
                [cell.imageView removeFromSuperview];
                cell.imageView.frame = cell.bounds;
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[_photosArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
                cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.imageView];

            UIButton *addBtn =[[UIButton alloc]init];
                 addBtn.tag=indexPath.row;
             deleteBtn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 19, 19);
                           UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_add_photo.png"];
                           [addBtn setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                           [addBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addBtnAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
               [cell.contentView addSubview:addBtn];
            return cell;
            }
    -(void)addBtnAction
     {

        UIAlertController *actionsheetController = [[UIAlertController alloc]init];

            UIAlertAction *library = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Choose from Library" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction
        * action)
                                      {
                                                // Library button tapped

                                                  [self performSelector:@selector(libraryBtnAction) withObject:nil];
                                           }];
                 [actionsheetController addAction:library];
            actionsheetController.view.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

                 [self presentViewController:actionsheetController animated:YES completion:nil];
            }

            -(void)libraryBtnAction
            {
                 UIImagePickerController *picker  = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
                 picker.delegate = self;
                 picker.allowsEditing = YES;
                 picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                 [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

            }
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{

                 chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
                 cell.imageView.image = chosenImage;
                 [_collectionView reloadData];

                 [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First problem in your code , you are using "cell" object in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` , where the hell you have defined that?
2. How you will specify in which image view of Collection cell, you will show the image picked from library?

JUST use a tag for tracking the things and in the end of picking the image just load the cell from the specific tag using indexpath.item and reload that specific cell.